Should I use free() after I return the pointer
the variable z is pointing to an address that has been freed free()
if I use malloc again can it use the memory that has been freed
I feel that this isn't right
char *conc(char *a, char *b){
    char *t = malloc(length(a) + length(b) + 1);
    for(int i = 0, n = length(a); i < n; i++){
        t[i] = a[i];
    }
    for(int j = 0, m = length(b); j < m; j++){
        t[length(a)+j] = b[j];
    }

    t[length(a) + length(b) + 1] = '\0';
    return t;
    free(t);
}

int main (void){

    char *x = "he";
    char *y = "llo dude";
    char *z = conc(x, y);


}

after allocating memory char *t = malloc(length(a) + length(b) + 1); and retuning the pointer, I freed the allocated memory return t; free(t); but it may happen that when i use malloc again it allocates the same memory address. But the variable z already points to that address char *z = conc(x, y);. Will this cause any problems?

Your free(t) is never reached.

OT: Use variable names that are descriptive. Generic variable names are a prodigious source of bugs in code.

The compiler should be reporting that the free() in the function is unreachable code... If you're not seeing this message, consult your documentation and work out how to increase the reporting level (sensitivity to poorly written code.) Pay attention to what the compiler reports. It knows far more about C than you or I ever will...

First of all, the free() function is never executed, because it's after the return. And to answer the question, yes, it would be wrong to free() the memory and then return a pointer to it. By returning the pointer to a memory segment that has been allocated by malloc(), you also pass on the responsibility to the caller to free() the memory after they are done with it.


after allocating memory char *t = malloc(length(a) + length(b) + 1);
and retuning the pointer, i freed the allocated memory return t; free(t);

That does not free the memory.  Execution of the function terminates when the return statement is executed, so the free() call afterward is never evaluated.

but it may happen that when i use malloc again it allocates
the same memory address.

You might not recognize it with Python and even C++ for comparison, but C is a high-level language.  Your wording belies thinking that is too low level. In particular, focusing on the address value is a mistake.
The concept you want here is object lifetime.  An object created via malloc() or another dynamic memory allocation function has "allocated" storage duration, meaning its lifetime begins when it is (explicitly) allocated, and continues until it is (explicitly) freed, or the program terminates.
Attempting to use an object before the beginning or after the end of its lifetime produces undefined behavior.  Thus, if you did free the allocated object before the function returned, then the caller could not safely use the return value for anything. On the other hand, if the allocated object is not freed before conc() is called again, then the new call to malloc will allocate a new, non-overlapping object, returning (therefore) a different value than the previous call.

But the variable z already points to that
address char *z = conc(x, y);. Will this cause any problems?

Attempting to use an object after the end of its lifetime produces undefined behavior.  The program presented isn't actually doing that, both because it does not actually free the memory and because it doesn't do anything with the returned pointer.  "Undefined" means we can't say exactly what would happen if the program were actuallly doing that, but this kind of error tends to produce observable program misbehavior.

The caller is responsible for freeing the memory block allocated, to which the pointer callee returns points.
The caller might not allocate this block of memory needed to be freed, as both in the following code and your code.
The programmer calling the function conc needs to pay attention to free this block of memory, otherwise, a memory leak will happen.
The codes might be as follows.

char *conc(char *a, char *b){ ...
// t = malloc(...
return t;
//    free(t); 
}

int main (void){
char *x = "he";
char *y = "llo dude";
char *z = conc(x, y);
//... reading z
free (z);

}


Yes, thank you.
Code frees the allocated block that the pointer points to.
